# (Initialization Error In Ubuntu 20.04) Error: Failure Reading Sector 0x100800 From HD1

Tags: boot, 20.04, hard-drive

Now about 20 minutes ago this error screen appeared when I turned on the PC in an unexpected way.

I forcibly had to turn it off due to the OS that had previously crashed after executing a code. So now I'm in doubt if it was this memory address 0x100800 internal hard drive that got corrupted and there is nothing more that can be done, or if there is any command where it is possible to restore data from the internal hard drive.

How could I proceed now? Will it be necessary to format the machine again and is it possible to backup data from the internal HD or came back to the same OS state?

Note: I'm also using an external hard drive and I'm still new on Linux, I uninstalled Windows 7 and installed Ubuntu 20.04 March of this year and this is the first time that I'm facing this issue.

I found similar issues like this around the net and in some pages, but I read that most users had their HD crashed or were passed procedures as LiveCD, LiveUSB that I don't have idea on how to perform... this laptop that is showing the issue is my only one.

[image: Screenshot of error: failure reading sector]

[image: Screenshot of GRUB]

Comment: You had to turn the machine off??   Was it impossible to safely shutdown (ie. SysRq commands direct to the kernel which allow safe shutdown via command to the linux kernel).   I had to power-off a box 3 times yesterday using power button (kernel panic mostly) & today I've decided it's hardware & box needs replacing...  (not worth effort trying to replace failed/failing components). Forcing a box off in an unclean manner is rarely wise - use SysRq or *safe* methods in future.  Boot *live* media & explore health & `fsck` your disk (ie. file-system check)

Comment: Use SMART to validate drive health - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools   (errors maybe logical or physical due to power being cut) which can be done via CLI tools or GUI tools if a desktop system is booted (you didn't say if desktop or server).  If drive is okay, and then you perform `fsck` or file-system check (from *live* media), you'll likely find you can boot in normally after reboot (ie. if `fsck` detects & fixes issues caused by power-outage/unclean-shutdown).

Comment: So, I was programming but I figure that I did a huge loop at my code and after that I ran it I crashed my OS, but it took more than 3 minutes to come back I decided to force the restart: pressed the power button to turn off, wait some sec and turned on again... But after the initial pc screen I faced the first screen: "error: failure reading sector..." and after the GRUB screen

Comment: I didn't know how could I do the ```SysRq```commands to safely before... This live media I am gonna give a search on it to know... Is still possible to recover data from the HD?? Live media I don't have, only the ISO from the Ubuntu 20.04 OS that I have installed it

Comment: I figure that SMART I can't able to use because after turn the laptop on and go to the GRUB screen I can't able to do these commands that are at the SMART tutorial, it was on desktop not server

Comment: Now I've inserted the same bootable pen drive (the same that I used to install Ubuntu 20.04) in my machine and it was read, after that it appeared that check disks and it showed no errors found on the directories

Comment: FYI:  Sysrq is a key on keyboards, though on modern keyboards it may not be printed; eg. it isn't on modern dells but is available if Fn key combination still; it's just no longer printed on keys (grab a phone & search "magic sysrq" and you'll find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key which is as good as any).  You boot a *live* system to perform checks on hardware; so drive is not being used allowing you to check health; and `fsck` (which is much more difficult on a running system, thus why you use the *live* system so only thumb-drive is being used; not your internal hdd/ssd/etc)

Comment: Oh now I saw here, I have this key Sysrq! I wasn't realizing before sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128010/discussion-between-victor-and-guiverc).

Comment: Sorry I access this site via Ubuntu SSO (ie. Ubuntu sign on), chat exists on Stack Exchange which I cannot access without logging into Stack Exchange (this browser I have restricted access to Ubuntu SSO). For *live* chat I'd recommend #ubuntu on IRC  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat)